# How to set a default value for a property of an Polymer object, on the basis of other properties

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I want set property's value for `Polymer` object from function, which depended from other properties, if default value not set

```
Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties : {
        a: String,
        b: String,
        c: {
            type: String,
            value: function() {return " " + this.a + " " + this.b}
        }
    },
    calcC: function() {return " " + this.a + " " + this.b}
});
```

How can i realize it?

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <p>a: {{a}}</p>
        <p>b: {{b}}</p>
        <p>c: {{c}}</p>
        <p>calc c: {{calcC()}}</p>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<my-element a="a" b="b"></my-element>
```

render

```
a: a

b: b

c: undefined undefined

calc c: undefined undefined
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rudux/kmrbs7h2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about

#### HTML

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
        <p>a: {{a}}</p>
        <p>b: {{b}}</p>
        <p>c: {{c}}</p>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<my-element a="a" b="b"></my-element>
<my-element a="a" b="b" c="c"></my-element>
```

#### JS

```
Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties: {
        a: String,
        b: String,
        c: String
    },
    ready: function () {
        if (this.c == undefined) {
            this.c = " " + this.a + " " + this.b;
        }
    }
});
```

#### Output

> a: a
>
> b: b
>
> c: a b
>
> a: a
>
> b: b
>
> c: c

Comment: Why not `ready` callback? I think this assignment leads to the regeneration of local DOM (in `ready` callback too). [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method)

Comment: `ready` would probably be better as it is "called after the element’s template has been stamped and all elements inside the element’s local DOM have been configured (with values bound from parents, deserialized attributes, or else default values)". I'll update the answer

Comment: What about regeneration of local DOM? Will it be generated twice?

Comment: Do you mean because I have 2 `<my-element>` tags? This is just to show the output if `c` is defined or not. It will be regenerated for each tag.

Comment: No. About "ready would probably be better as it is "called after the element’s template has been stamped and all elements inside the element’s local DOM have been configured". Properties changes in `ready` callback will regenerate DOM with new value?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, this will mean the DOM will need to be regenerated but until the attributes are deserialized you wont know the values of `a`, `b` or `c` which is why they were appearing as undefined in `calcC`